# jQplot different time format on xaxis and highlight

Tags: time, format, highlight, jqplot

I have some series on jQplot for which I have set highlight options. My idea is to use %H:%M:%S for time format in highlight and %H:%M but cant set it.

```
        axes:{
            xaxis:{
                autoscale: true,
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                tickOptions: {
                    showTicks: true,
                    formatString:'%e %b %H:%M:%S',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                },
            },
        },
        highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 12,
            tooltipContentEditor: customTooltip,
            formatString: '#serieLabel#<br/>%s | %s',
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a different date/time format in the tooltip (highlight) than the date/time format used on the x-axis, rather than using `formatString` you can use the `tooltipContentEditor` to define a function that will return the formatted string to display in the tooltip.

Assuming you want the x-axis to show dates in the format `%e %b %H:%M:%S` (e.g. 29 Oct 04:12:12) but you want the tooltip to show them in the format `%H:%M` (e.g. 12:12) you can use the following code (unchanged from your code snippet above) to define the `axes`:

```
axes: {
  xaxis: {
    autoscale: true,
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    tickOptions: {
      showTicks: true,
      formatString: '%e %b %H:%M:%S',
      fontSize: '11px',
    },
  },
},
```

and the following code to define the `highlighter`:

```
highlighter: {
  show: true,
  sizeAdjust: 12,
  tooltipContentEditor: function(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
    // x-axis value
    var date = series[seriesIndex][pointIndex][0];
    // jqPlot formatter function for date/time (used by $.jqplotDateTickFormatter)
    var formatter = $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter;
    // Do the formatting
    var formattedDate = formatter('%H:%M', date);
    // y-axis value for series hovered over
    var seriesValue = series[seriesIndex][pointIndex][1];
    return '#serieLabel#<br/>' + formattedDate + '|' + seriesValue;

  }
},
```

Here we are using a custom function `tooltipContentEditor` which retrieves the date/time from the series hovered over and formats it using $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter. The function then concatenates the strings together to return the text to display in the tooltip. The key lines for formatting the date/time correctly are:

```
// DateAxisRenderer
var formatter = $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter;
// Do the formatting
var formattedDate = formatter('%H:%M', date);
```

This produces the following tooltip when a data point is hovered over:

[image]

A working example can be [seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/bhyaj35o/3/).

Comment: Great. You make my day!And how about opposite formating - on xaxis - %H:%M and highlighter %H:%M:%S ?

Comment: For the `axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString` use `%e %b %H:%M`, and for the call to $.jqplot.DateTickFormatter in `highlighter.tooltipContentEditor` use `%H:%M:%S`. Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jebywwnu/1/) for an example.

Comment: Great. Thank you.